# Typecasting in C program

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with typecasting.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *
input_from_args(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  if (argc == 1){
    return stdin;
  }else{
    return fopen(argv[1], "r");
  }
}

void
tokenize(FILE *src)
{
  char buffer[80];

  if (fgets(buffer, 80, src) == NULL){
    fprintf(stdout, "The line is NULL");
  }else{
    fprintf(stdout,"%s\n", buffer);
    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(src, "%s", &buffer[i]) && buffer[i] != '\n'){
      if(buffer[i] == ' '){
    i++  ;
      }else if (buffer[i]=='+'){
    fprintf(stdout,"+    Addition operator\n");
    i++;
      }else if (buffer[i]=='-'){
    fprintf(stdout,"-    Subtraction operator\n");
    i++;
      }else if (buffer[i]=='*'){
    fprintf(stdout,"*    Multiplication operator\n");
    i++;
      }else if (buffer[i]=='/'){
    fprintf(stdout,"-    Division operator\n");
    i++;
      }else if (buffer[i]=='^'){
    fprintf(stdout,"-    Exponentiation operator\n");
    i++;
      }else if( buffer[i]== '>'){
    if(buffer[i+=1] == '='){
      fprintf(stdout, ">=    Comparison Operator\n");
      i+=2;
    }else{
      fprintf(stdout,">    Comparison Operator\n");
      i+=1;
    }
      }else if( buffer[i]== '<'){
    if(buffer[i+=1] == '='){
      fprintf(stdout, "<=    Comparison Operator\n");
      i+=2;
    }else{
      fprintf(stdout,"<    Comparison Operator\n");
      i+=1;
    }
      }else if (isdigit((int)buffer[i])){
    fprintf(stdout, "%d    Simple Numeral\n",buffer[i]);
    i++;
      }else if (buffer[i] == ')'){
    i++;
      }else if (buffer[i] == '('){
    i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
int
main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

  FILE* src = input_from_args(argc, argv);
  tokenize(src);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to type cast in the `isdigit` function. It compiles fine but when it prints the digit, it's not the correct number. For example if `buffer[i] == '4'` then it prints 52

Any help is appreciated

Comment: In the handlers for `<=` and `>=` you advance `i` too far

Comment: Look into the `switch` construct, or even better, a lookup table.  Also you should be including a length limit in the `fscanf` format string in order to avoid buffer overflow, and I don't think `fscanf("%s"` can ever give you `\n`, it skips whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're printing an ASCII digit as an integer. The ASCII value of `'4'` is `52`. Change to:

```
    fprintf(stdout, "%c    Simple Numeral\n",buffer[i]);
```

Your typecast in the call to `isdigit()` is completely unnecessary (and unrelated).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `52` because that's the ASCII code point<sup>1</sup> for the character `'4'`, as per the following graphic:

[image]

If you want to print it as a character, you should be using `%c` rather than `%d` in your `printf` statement:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%c    Simple Numeral\n",buffer[i]);
```

> As an aside, I'm not entirely certain why you're using `fprintf(stdout,...` rather than just `printf(...`. The latter is functionally identical and would result in a lot less typing on your part.

---

<sup>1</sup> ASCII isn't *required* by the standard but it's by far the most common and, more importantly here, what *you* appear to be using.

Comment: its also just a habit to use fprintf. As far as I know it wont really affect anything.